# How to expose services between containers with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, circleci

On circleci, when I declare multiple dockers for a job:

```
dockers:
   app: company/image
   selenium: selenium/image
```

app will expose a port 4000 and selenium will expose port 4444.
Then from app container, I can access selenium service via localhost:4444, and on selenium container, I can access app webserver via localhost:4000.

docker-compose, however, behaves differently. I only allow me to access to selenium:4444 from app, and app:4000 from selenium.

I want docker-compose to behave similar to circleci, in which it allows me to use localhost:port to access other services. How can I do that?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/ ?  You can use `expose` to expose ports to other services but not the host; use `ports` to expose ports to the host. [It's all in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) and there are many guides.

Comment: yes, docker-compose ports settings allow access from a container to another container via "container:port", not "localhost:port".

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve the above is via `networking_mode`:

I need to tell docker-compose to run selenium using `networking_mode = "services:app"` so that every ports listened by selenium will be available to access from app using just `localhost:PORT` (and vice versa)

This is explained here: [Can docker-compose share an ip between services with discrete ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688218/can-docker-compose-share-an-ip-between-services-with-discrete-ports)

Also the reason for it to work is explained in the docker networking model here: https://codability.in/docker-networking-explained/